# (SSRS) multiple parameters in Value field of Group Filter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have to filter a group field value based on two parameters. So in the group properties, in filters, I want to put two multi-valued parameters in 'Value'.

Expression: Field!metric.value

Operator: IN

Value: =(Parameters!MetricPara1.Value, Parameters!MetricPara2.Value)

These two parameters have nothing in common. I'm getting error. Is there a way?

Comment: also i have to mention that the parameters are multi-valued

Comment: I'm not at my work PC now to look at the group filter method but can you move the filtering out to the dataset query instead? So your query would contain something like `WHERE (metric in (@MetricParam1) or metric in (@MetricParam2))` . That's the approach I would normally take, as it also means less data returned from the database.

Comment: Thanks, but i tried that approach in SQL, and the rendering becomes very slow since the parameter has a lot of values. But anyhow, i created another column altogether for the field corresponding to MetricPara2. So now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as an expression in Value

```
=JOIN(Parameters!MetricPara1.Value,",") + JOIN(Parameters!MetricPara2.Value,",")
```

Comment: its not working. I tried using just JOIN(Parameters!MetricPara1.Value,",") too, still not working. It works only when its Parameters!MetricPara1.Value